# Accesing the javascript variable in html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to "html" and "Javascript".

I have the following piece of code using "html" and "Javascript" as

```
<script>
    var number=10000;
</script>
<input type="text" value="">
```

I want to use the value of "number" variable,as the "value" attribute of "input" tag. How?

Comment: Have you considered just putting the value in the input instead of in a script?

Comment: @NIET,In my actual code,the value of number is dynamic value getting from  server.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML

Comment: Okay... `<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($yourValue); ?>" />`?

Comment: I dont know about php,

Comment: @reddy just copy/paste what Niet wrote and change `$yourvalue` to the value it needs to be

Comment: Can I use, <input type="text" value="<script>document.write(a)</script>" >

Comment: Now, we all have to guess and make an assumption server?

Comment: What languages do you speak? English, HTML, Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Framework AngularJS, which supports this exact use
(http://angularjs.org/)
It's called DataBinding.
Your could would look like this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="number"/>
</div>

<script>
    var myController = function($scope) {
        $scope.number = 10000;  
    };
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L3hrv/

You could also change the javascript to the following:

```
<script>
var number=10000;
window.onload = function() { //is executed when the window finished loading
  document.getElementById('my-id').setAttribute('value', number);  //changes the value of the specified element
}
</script>

<input id="my-id" type="text" value="">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3G44/

Comment: Can I use, <input type="text" value="<script>document.write(a)</script>" >

Comment: No thats not working, the value would be actually this: <script>document.write(a)</script>.  Theres no way to access javascript within the value attribute with native javascript

Comment: That means,within the html tags,we can't use native javascript.

Comment: It depends, there are several attributes that "execute" code (e.g. onclick or onload), but value isn't one of them

Comment: If you want to get started in HTML5 and JavaScript you should try the tutorials from W3Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp for HTML, http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp for JavaScript).

Comment: In this case the js code not exceuted?

Comment: you should consider accepting answer in your questions,

Comment: if you put code into the value-attribute it wont be executed, only in other attributes (events) like onload onclick or onerror

Answer (score 2):

Similar to John Smiths answer, but with jQuery.  I personally find it easier to work with.  I know it's not necessarily what you're asking but it may help.

**This will target all input tags**

```
    var number=10000;
    $('input').attr('value' , number);

    <input type="text">
```

**Add an ID to just target one**

```
    var number2=50000;
    $('#yourId').attr('value' , number2);

    <input id="yourId" type="text">
```

**Add a Class to target as many as you like**

```
    var number3=70000;
    $('.yourClass').attr('value' , number3);

    <input class="yourClass" type="text">  
    <input class="yourClass" type="text">  
    <input class="yourClass" type="text">  
    <input class="yourClass" type="text">
```

Here's an example with some brief explanations:
**http://jsfiddle.net/wE6bD/**

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using jQuery

```
$('#inputID').val(number);
```

Just add an id tag to the input. (id='inputID')

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the DOM:

```
    <script>
        var number=10000;
    </script>
    <input id = "myInput" type="text" value="" />  
    <script>
        document.getElementById("myInput").value = number;
    </script>
```

Comment: Can I use, <input type="text" value="<script>document.write(a)</script>" > like this

Comment: no, il will not work : the content of the 'value' attribute is just text, the browser will not interpret the JS code.