# Accessing the javascript code inside the html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to "html" and "Javascript".

```
<p id="pid"></p>
<script>
     abc="hello";
     document.getElementById("pid").innerHTML=abc;
</script>
<input type="text" 
             value="<script>document.getElementById("pid").innerHTML</script>"/>
```

How the code gets executed in the above case.

Comment: Your code is all over the place, might be wise to look up the Value attribute of the input tag... there a hundreds of code examples available, why do you not just Google?

Comment: do you want to get `<p>` tag text and paste into `textbox`?

Comment: I believe you already asked this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682955/accesing-the-javascript-variable-in-html-tag/22683095#22683095

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to set a value of the input field to be equal to the content of the `pid` paragraph. In this case you should set `value` property of the HTMLInputElement. You can get a reference to it using `getElementById` (there are many ways to get this element object) which you already know how to use. For example:

```
<p id="pid"></p>
<input type="text" id="input" />

<script>
    var abc = "hello";
    var pid = document.getElementById("pid");

    pid.innerHTML = abc;
    document.getElementById("input").value = pid.innerHTML;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

the content of the 'value' attribute is just text, the browser will not interpret the JS code.

You can use the DOM instead:

```
 <p id="pid"></p>
 <script>
 abc="hello";
 document.getElementById("pid").innerHTML=abc;
 </script>
 <input id = "myInput" type="text" value="" />  
 <script>
    document.getElementById("myInput").value = abc;
    //OR : document.getElementById("myInput").value = getElementById("pid").innerHTML;
 </script>
```

see : [Accesing the javascript variable in html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682955/accesing-the-javascript-variable-in-html-tag/22683152)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
<script>
  function myFunction(){
    var abc="hello";
    document.getElementById("pid").innerHTML=abc;
  }
</script>

<p id="pid"></p>

<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="myFunction();" >
```